# Use global variables in other functions doesn't work

Tags: python

This is a simplified example of my problem. I need to use a variable which I have created in another function, but putting `global` before the variable instantiation doesn't work.

```
x = 10
def one():
    global x
    a = x +2
    b = a/2
    print (b)
def two():            
    one()             
    c = int(input())            
def three():
    global a
    global c           
    d = c + a         
    print(b)

two()         
three()
```

Comment: If you `return` the value from the function then you can use it outside of the function itself.

Comment: Well, if you want these variables to be global, you should _make_ them global - define them in the outer scope.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Answer (score 2):

To use a global variables in Python you need to declare them as such:

```
x = 10

def one():
    global x
    global a
    global b
    a = x +2
    b = a/2
    print (b)

def two():            
    one()             
    global c
    c = int(input())            

def three():
    global a
    global c           
    d = c + a         
    print(d)
    print(b)

two()       
three()
```

In Python, a variable defined on top of the file (not within a function, an if statement etc) is considered as a global variable and is accessible throughout the file (in other functions etc) but also to any file importing that file.

A variable defined in a scope other than the main body (say a function) it's accessible to that function only. In this case, if you define a new variable within a body other than the main body, you need to tell Python that this variable is global just before you create the variable. Similarly, if you need to access a global variable, you need to use `global var` just before you try to access it.

Not the best implementation. I will recommend, as others already did, to use a class or functions with arguments and returns instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really helped me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `return` statement and function parameters:

```
x = 10
def one(x):
    a = x +2
    b = a/2
    print(b)
    return a, b

def two():                        
    c = int(input()) 
    return c    

def three(a, b, c)                 :         
    d = c + a         
    print(b)

a, b = one(x)
c = two()         
three(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to move these three functions into some class, create an 'x' attribute in this class, and then use this 'x' in the functions above as self.x